# Why Python print is not working properly in Windows prompt?

Tags: python, windows, printing, output, prompt

First of all I'm a newbie in Python. I have this print line that works as expected in the Python shell but not in the Windows 7 Pro command prompt. This is the code that repeats inside a loop:

```
print(format(line_number + 1, '2.0f') + " " +\
      formatted_datelst[0])
```

In the Python shell I get this (expected):
[Python Shell output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh6Gn.jpg)

In the Windows 7 Pro command prompt I get this (unexpected):
[Windows 7 Pro command prompt output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9b5H.jpg)

As you can see in the Windows prompt the line number is not being printed. Even more strange, in the Windows 7 Home command prompt I do get the expected output. Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found it myself.

I was inadvertently passing a carriage return code `\r` in the beginning of `formatted_datelst[0]`. In the Windows 7 Home machine this had been removed automatically by a text editor I had used for the input file. (As I said, I'm a newbie in Python :)